# Error invalid signer from Goerli when sending transaction to the smart contract using rust ethers.rs library

Tags: rust, transactions, smartcontracts

I'm using Rust library ethers.rs to call a smart contract's method on the Goerli
The following is my preparation steps:

1. Create provider from rpc_url then set signer to create SignerMiddleware
2. Create a SmartContract struct from generated code using ethers_rs's AbiGen
3. Create a FunctionCall from the smartcontract address and the client from step 1
4. Call method FunctionCall.send() from functionCall's object then received message "Error: (code: -32000, message: invalid sender, data: None)"

Here my snippet

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    set_up_logs();
    let execute_param = "SOMERAWDATA";
    //Working url
    let rpc_url = "https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/{APIKEY}";
    let contract_addr = "0x1577875Dd69f5276AEEabE3540b1F7c64690b3F8";
    let signer = OWNER_PRIVATE_KEY.parse::<LocalWallet>()?;
    info!(
        "Call from address {:?}",
        hex::encode(signer.address().as_bytes()).as_str()
    );
    let signer_middleware = Provider::<Http>::try_from(rpc_url)?.with_signer(signer.clone());
    //info!("Default sender {:?}", provider.default_sender());
    let client = Arc::new(signer_middleware);
    let address: Address = contract_addr.parse()?;
    let contract = ScalarGateway::new(address.clone(), client.clone());
    let params = Bytes::from_hex(execute_param)?;
    let contract_call = contract.execute(params);
    let res = contract_call.send().await?.await;
    info!("Call result {:?}", &res);
    Ok(())
}
```

Thank you all for your helps!

When i've tried to call the smart contract method "execute" from the nodejs code it worked fine and returned a TransactionReceipt from Goerli. I guess ethers.rs generates the signature somehow differently from how nodejs lib does.

Any clues to resolve the issues?